# What is the most efficient way to get properties from an array object?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, properties, react-hooks

I want to collect the names (Jenny, Tiffany, etc.) that are stored in every object. and these objects live in an array. I've used `Array.prototype.every()` and `Array.prototype.forEach()`, but I don't think they are the right methods.

*I also want to note that majority of these codes are from Codaffection. I am practicing on developing in React.*

If you would like to experiment with the code, [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/06142021-feenu?file=/src/pages/Employees/Employees.js:2391-2606).

In every object, there is an id, fullname, email and etc.

[image: Properties in Objects]

This is the code that adds, edits, generates unique ids for each employee, and gets all storage data.

```
const KEYS = {
    employees: 'employees',
    employeeId: 'employeeId'
}

export function insertEmployee(data) {
    let employees = getAllEmployees();
    data['id'] = generateEmployeeId()
    employees.push(data)
    localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employees, JSON.stringify(employees))
}

export function updateEmployee(data) {
    let employees = getAllEmployees();
    let recordIndex = employees.findIndex(x => x.id == data.id);
    employees[recordIndex] = { ...data }
    localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employees, JSON.stringify(employees));
}

export function generateEmployeeId() {
    if (localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId) == null)
        localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employeeId, '0')
    var id = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId))
    localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employeeId, (++id).toString())
    return id;
}

export function getAllEmployees() {
    if (localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employees) == null)
        localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employees, JSON.stringify([]))
    let employees = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employees));
    //map departmentID to department title
    let departments = getDepartmentCollection();
    return employees.map(x => ({
        ...x,
        department: departments[x.departmentId - 1].title
    }))
}
```

This is how new employees are being added and updated.

```
const [records, setRecords] = useState(employeeService.getAllEmployees());

const addOrEdit = (employee, resetForm) => {
    if (employee.id == 0) employeeService.insertEmployee(employee);
    else employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
    resetForm();
    setRecords(employeeService.getAllEmployees());
}
```

This is how values are being inputted and addOrEdit function is being triggered.

```
const initialFValues = {
  id: 0,
  fullName: "",
  email: "",
  mobile: "",
  city: "",
  gender: "male",
  departmentId: "",
  hireDate: new Date(),
  isPermanent: false
};

<Controls.Input
  name="fullName"
  label="Full Name"
  value={values.fullName}
/>
<Controls.Input
  label="Email"
  name="email"
  value={values.email}
/>
<Controls.Input
  label="Mobile"
   name="mobile"
  value={values.mobile}

/>

<Controls.Button type="submit" text="Submit" />

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validate()) {
      addOrEdit(values, resetForm);
    }
};
```

This is how I am trying to capture the names: Jenny, Tiffany, and etc.

```
const listOfNames = () => {
    var nameList = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    var eachName = nameList.forEach(employee.fullName); // <- This is the problem.
    console.log("List of Employees: ", nameList);
};
```

If you would like to experiment with the code, [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/06142021-feenu?file=/src/pages/Employees/Employees.js:2391-2606).

Comment: Oh, it does! But I wasn't planning to add them in their own array. This is a good start and I will try to figure out how to parse them individually from this new array. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `forEach`.

```
const listOfNames = () => {
    var nameList = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    var eachName = nameList.map(employee => employee.fullName);
    console.log("List of Employees: ", eachName);
};
```

This should solve it. :)

Comment: Thank you! I will remember that from here on forth!